# Displaying a particular entity of a field

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have database named '***ecc***'.

Database '***ecc***' contains table '***client***' and table '***task***'

Table '***ecc***' has fields like '***ProjectManager***' '***CompanyName***' '***CompanyStreetAddress***' '***ZipCode***' '***CompanyPhone***'

Table '***task***' has fields like '***assignedto***' , '***subject***' , '***date***'

Data type for date is used properly.

In below code the content of select list are extracted from the field '***ProjectManager***' of table '***client***'.

The selected content of select list is stored in field '***assignedto***' along with that respective Subject for field '***subject***' and Date for field '***date***' are inserted into table '***task***' by user.

My issue: **Whenever user select the content of select list which is extracted from table '***client***' of field '***ProjectManager***' its respective fields '***CompanyName***' '***CompanyStreetAddress***' '***ZipCode***' '***CompanyPhone***' should be displayed under **text area.****

```
    <html>
    <body>

    <form action = "select.php" method ="POST">

    <?php

        error_reporting(-1);

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','ecc');

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {

        die('Can not connect to DB error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '.$mysqli->connect_error);

    }

        echo "Select client";

    if($results = $mysqli->query("SELECT ProjectManager FROM client"))
    {
        ?>

            <select name="project_manager">
            <option value="">-select project manager-</option>

        <?php

    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

   ?><option value="<?php echo $row['ProjectManager'] ?>"><?php echo $row['ProjectManager'] ?></option>

   <?php

   }  

    ?>

    <br>

    </select>

    <?php $results->free(); }?>

    <br><br>
    Subject:<br>

    <input type="text" name="subject"><br>

    <br>

    Date: <br>

    <input type = "date" name = "date"><br>

    <br><br>

    <textarea rows="5" cols="5" readonly="" value = "Client Details"> 

    <?php 

     if(isset($_POST['project_manager'])){

        $assignedto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_manager']);

        $sql = "SELECT 
                CompanyName, CompanyStreetAddress, City, State, Zipcode, CompanyPhone 
                FROM `client` 
                WHERE 
                ProjectManager = '$assignedto'";

        echo $sql;
         }
    ?>

    </textarea>

    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">



    </form>

    </body>

    </html>



    <?php
    if(  isset($_POST['project_manager']) && isset($_POST['subject'])  && isset($_POST['date']) ){

        print_r($_POST);
            $assignedto = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['project_manager']);
            $subject = $mysqli->real_escape_string( $_POST['subject']);
            $date =  $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date']);


        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO task (assignedto,subject,date) VALUES(?,?,?)")){

        $stmt->bind_param('sss',$assignedto,$subject,$date);

                $stmt->execute();
                $rows_affected = $stmt->affected_rows;

                if($rows_affected >0){

               echo "inserted successfully";    

            }elseif($rows_affected === -1){

               echo 'there is an error inserting';    

            }elseif($rows_affected === NULL){

            echo "invalid argument supplied";    

            }

        }    
    }
```

It would be grate if someone rewrite it

Thank you

Comment: Which line is line 60?

Comment: Where is line `60` in your code?

Comment: echo "$mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `CompanyStreetAddress` FROM `client` WHERE project_manager = '.$assignedto.'")";
  @mkaatman @SaidbakR

Comment: Start by getting rid of the outer quotes. You don't want to display that line as literal text.

Comment: Its still not displaying the the respective fields 'CompanyName' 'CompanyStreetAddress' 'ZipCode' 'CompanyPhone'  under text area. @mkaatman

Comment: Split this into two lines: `echo $mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT \`CompanyStreetAddress\` FROM \`client\` WHERE project_manager = '.$assignedto.'");`. Save the query as $sql and echo $sql. Run that query that outputs directly against the db.

Comment: Still not working @mkaatman